What counts as a "structure" for first-order theories?
In Moschovakis's Notes On Set Theory (excerpts screenshots here), Moschovakis writes:

The axiomatic setup. We assume at the outset that there is a domain or universe $\mathcal{W}$ of objects, some of which are sets, and certain definite conditions and operations on $\mathcal{W}$, among them the basic conditions of identity, sethood, and membership:
$x = y \longleftrightarrow x$ is the same object as $y$
$Set(x) \longleftrightarrow x$ is a set
$x \in y \longleftrightarrow Set(y)$ and $x$ is a member of $y$
We call the objects which are not sets atoms, but we do not require that any atoms exist, i.e. it may be the case that all the objects are sets.
We have assumed...the standard universe of objects $\mathcal{W}$, in which axioms (I) - (VI) (at least) are true.

The more common notation (I think?) for this "domain" or "universe" is $V$, but the same concept pertains: presuming that the axioms are consistent, we can assume that some such "domain" or "universe", conforming to the axioms, does in fact exist (even though we haven't given any explicit description of a model). In fact, our ability to assume this seems essential to having any "foundational" theory at all. Otherwise we would end up in a situation of infinte regress: existence of a universe of discourse for theory $T$ depends on defining a model within another theory $T'$, but establishing a universe of discourse for $T'$ depends on defining a model within some third theory $T''$, and so on.
But surely there's nothing magic about $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in this regard, it's just one first-order theory. So presumably(?) whe can (in principle) consider any consistent set of first-order axioms $\mathsf{T}$ to be a "foundational" theory, in which case I should be able to legitimately assume (without explicitly defining a model, or relying on some other antecedent theory) that there exists some "domain" $\mathfrak{T}$ of objects which satisfies the axioms of $\mathsf{T}$.
My question (assuming the above is basically correct): Is this "domain $\mathfrak{T}$" a structure? (even though $\mathfrak{T}$ is inherently not in any sense "definable", I just assume its existence as a consequence of the axioms' consistency) Or does the term "structure" only pertain to models that have been defined in an explicit way?

Let me briefly review the meta-theory / object-theory distinction.
The meta-theory consists of the basic axioms and deduction rules we use when we do mathematics. In reality, the meta-theory we actually use the vast majority of the time is an informal one based in natural language, i.e., the kinds of proofs written in prose that you find in papers and books. But for the purposes of clarity in this discussion, we can take the meta-theory to be something a bit more precise, like $\mathsf{ZFC}$ set theory.
When we're doing mathematical logic, we want to study the structure of logical reasoning and prove things about theories. These theories we're proving things about are object theories. They are abstract mathematical objects, e.g., a theory $T$ is a set of sentences. To prove things about $T$, it's helpful to associate a semantics to $T$, with a notion of model. Here we give a general definition of a structure: a set, equipped with distinguished functions and relations that interpret the symbols in the language. And we can prove the completeness theorem: For a first-order theory $T$, if $T$ is consistent, then it has a model. This is all well and good, because everything here is a mathematical object that we can reason about using the tools of the meta-theory.
Now you might ask: what are the semantics of the meta-theory? The most important thing to realize is that the meta-theory does not need semantics. It's totally coherent to take a formalist view and say that the meta-theory is not really about anything. When we prove things in the meta-theory, we're just pushing symbols around on paper according to prescribed rules.
Depending on your philosophy of mathematics, you may believe there is a true universe of sets that provides a semantics to our meta-theoretic $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Or you may believe that there are many possible universes of sets. But whatever these universes are, they're definitely not structures (in the formal sense defined above)! Remember, a structure is a set. It's a thing in the universe.
[Note: We can also form the object-theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and by the completeness theorem, if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent, it has a model. But there is a distinction between a model for the object-theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (which is a precisely defined mathematical object) and a semantic universe for the meta-theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (which is not).]
Even if you don't believe there is a true universe of sets out there, it may be comforting (and helpful to guide your intuition) to imagine that the meta-theory is actually talking about a domain of real things. If this is your point of view, then the Moschovakis quote you included in your question is just a "way of talking". We have a hypothetical universe, and if we prove $\exists x\, \varphi(x)$, rather than just being symbols on paper, we can interpret this as meaning "there is some $x$ in our hypothetical universe satisfying $\varphi$".
Personally, I doubt that there is a "real" universe of sets, and I even doubt that there is a "real" infinite natural number system to serve as a universe for arithmetic theories like $\mathsf{PA}$. But I still think it's coherent to reason logically using $\mathsf{ZFC}$ or $\mathsf{PA}$ as a foundation for mathematics. This amounts to thinking about a hypothetical universe, as in the last paragraph: if you show me a universe satisfying the axioms, our theorems will be true in that universe. This is a meaningful statement, even if we  remain agnostic about whether such a universe actually exists.

This is very helpful. A couple points I'm not fully clear on, though. Firstly, regarding "the metatheory does not need semantics": If one views the metatheory ($\mathsf{ZFC}$, say) in this strictly formalist way, i.e. devoid of semantics (not describing any "universe" that in any sense "exists"), doesn't that force you into a similarly formalist view of any object-theory $\mathsf{T}$ defined "within" this metatheory? That is, what could any $L_{\mathsf{T}}$-structure be "made of" or "built from", if not from "objects" (i.e sets) of a metatheory "universe"?

No, because object theories and $L$-structures are quite different sorts of things: they are purely abstract. When you work within the metatheory, "existence" no longer refers to real existence in the world, but rather to provable existence from the metatheory. So I'm quite happy to assert the mathematical statement "$\mathbb{N}$ exists" because my metatheory proves it. @NikS

Not sure if I know the right terminology, but it sounds like you’re saying: The Platonist might say that the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ metatheory describes a universe which exists in a fairly concrete sense sort of independently of the thoughts/actions of human mathematicians. But the Formalist says that $\omega$, $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$, etc., exist in a more abstract, conceptual, and “contingent” sense: if we accept the axioms, then implicitly we accept the existence of an inductive set, its power set, etc. (because the axioms logically imply their existence). Am I reading you correctly?

@NikS Something like that. Our axioms give us robust tools for reasoning about the "world of mathematics". $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$, $L$-structures, etc. exist in the world of mathematics. Does the world of mathematics itself exist? Opinions differ, but it doesnt matter if we disagree about this, because as long we all agree on the axioms for reasoning about the world of mathematics, we can do so productively.

This has been very informative. But I’m surprised that nothing I’ve read before now has articulated with any specificity this distinction between a “structure” and a “semantic universe for the meta-theory”, and that books on mathematical logic don’t say much of anything about “background” meta-theoretic assumptions as “context” for the object theories (certainly the popular books by Enderton and by Ebbinghaus et. al. say nothing about these points). Do you happen to know of any books (or maybe detailed lecture notes) that really go into these topics?

@NikS That's probably because "semantic universe for the metatheory" is not a mathematical concept, and its existence is a philosophical question, not a mathematical one. Math books tend to do math and avoid philosophizing. IIRC, Kunen is careful to set up the metatheory / object theory distinction in his books.

Thanks. With regard to the boundary between “mathematics” and “philosophy”, I’m not sure I agree with where that line tends to get drawn. I’m reminded of a comment by Tim Chow on a MathOverflow question stating (to paraphrase from memory) that we can’t avoid the fact that mathematics inevitably involves some philosophical assumptions. It seems like the teaching of mathematics (at least the “foundations” subjects) should at least touch on this “philosophical” dimension. In any case, I’ll take a look at Kunen.

There's a lot to unpack here.
First, there is no fundamental difference in this context between a structure and a model. I guess the term “structure”, which comes from universal algebra, is more frequently used for a set with operations but no relations, unlike a model which can also interpret relations; however I don't think this distinction is consistent in the literature, and I have definitely seen “structure” used as a synonym of “model”. On the other hand, the term “model” is a bit more general because there are many kinds of logic beyond (classical) first-order logic (propositional, second-order, monadic second-order, propositional second-order, higher-order, intuitionistic, linear, type theory, …) and all these logics have models that look different than structures (Kripke models, toposes, cartesian closed categories, …), but in the context of first-order logic, a model is just a structure (with relations).
Next, the assertion that every consistent theory has a model is Gödel's completeness theorem, which is an actual theorem with a proof, not some base assumption or axiom, and if you look at the proof of the completeness theorem, it does actually build a model (called the “syntactic model”).
When proving the completeness theorem, we are reasoning in ZFC, just like we do in all mathematics by convention (though most mathematics can also work in much weaker theories like second-order arithmetic, or substantially different theories like type theory).

Regarding the structure / model distinction: In first-order logic, a structure (more formally, an $L$-structure) is a set equipped with interpretations of the symbols in the language $L$. Given a theory $T$, a model (of $T$) is an $L$-structure satisfying the axioms of $T$. I always try to avoid writing things like "let $M$ be a model" unless I have a theory in mind in the background. But in model theory, it's so common to have a fixed theory $T$ in the background, that this distinction has slipped, and it's common to see "model" and "structure" used as if they were synonyms.

I'm not sure of the history, but I don't think "structure" comes originally from universal algebra. As far as I'm aware, early work in universal algebra called structures "algebras". The term structure (as a concept to be formally defined, rather than an informal usage) may have originated in Bourbaki, where it is used for something much more general than $L$-structures. In particular, I'm not aware of any connotation that structures should not have relation symbols.
